# adding item/action to pyqtgraph PlotWidget context menu

Tags: python-3.x, contextmenu, pyqtgraph

I'm new to python and pyqt5/pyqtgraph.  Trying to add an action/item to the context menu of a PlotWidget using the code below.  The New_Item appears overlaid on top of the "View All" item in the context menu [have picture, but as a new user, not allowed to post it :-(] instead of above it.  I think I'm adding a new context menu (instead of accessing the default context menu and adding to it).  I'd appreciate guidance with figuring out what I'm doing wrong.  Thanks in advance for the help!

```py
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
import pyqtgraph as pg
    
class Plot(pg.PlotWidget):
           
    def contextMenuEvent(self, event):
        menu = QtWidgets.QMenu(self)
        someAction = menu.addAction('New_Item')
    
        res = menu.exec_(event.globalPos())
        if res == someAction:
            print('Hello')
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    plot = Plot()
    plot.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())][1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code saved my day! I was also confused about how to create a customized context menu. Many thanks!

If you are still working out this issue,

```
class Plot(pg.PlotWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setMenuEnabled(False)

    def contextMenuEvent(self, event):
        menu = QtWidgets.QMenu(self)
        someAction = menu.addAction('New_Item')

        res = menu.exec_(event.globalPos())
        if res == someAction:
            print('Hello')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    plot = Plot()
    plot.show()
    app.exec_()
```

Use `setMenuEnabled(False)` to disable the default context menu. It just does nothing to your customized context menu and everything works fine.